# onRequest Firebase function seems to replace the response parameter object on exception

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

I'm currently trying to unit test my HTTPS functions. I would like to test my error responses so I voluntarily cause an exception in my https function. I catch an error displayed in the `console.debug(e)` but the `res.status().json()` that I provide in my unit tests is never called, and so the `done()` function is never called neither.

However, it seems that when the `onCreateUserAndAgency()` is successful, the `res.json()` that I provide is called, and the test is successful.

Is there a step when the Response object is replaced in case of an exception ? Am I doing something wrong ?

The stack I use is `Firebase Functions` with `Typescript` and `Mocha` for unit testing.

```js
export default functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    /* here, when I put res.status(200).json({}), the test's successful so it means done() is called */
    onCreateUserAndAgency({
        body: req.body,
    }).then(r => {
        res.json(r);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.debug(e);
        res.status(e.error.status).json(e);
    })
});
```

```js
describe('User', async function() {
  describe('#createUser()', async function() {
    it('should return error 500 for unknown errors', async function(done) {
      const req: any = { };
      const res: any = {
        status: (status: number) => {
          assert.equal(status, 500);
          console.log("TEST");
          done();
        },
        json: (data: any) => {
          console.log("TEST");
          done();
        } 
      };
      fcts.createUserViaEmail(req, res);
    });
  });
});
```

The error log :

```
> test
> mocha --require ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts

{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail"}


  User
    #createUser()
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
    at onCreateUserAndAgency (C:\Users\Orionss\Projets\PATH\functions\src\users\on-create.ts:20:70)
... Many less specific error lines
{
  error: {
    status: 500,
    message: "Une erreur inattendue s'est produite.",
    date: 2021-12-21T14:04:42.842Z
  }
}
      1) should return error 500 for unknown errors


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) User
       #createUser()
         should return error 400 for missing info:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Users\Orionss\Projets\PATH\functions\test\main.spec.ts)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Comment: You might also have a look at this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813013/test-will-not-call-done-when-failing)

Answer (score 1):

I found where the error was

The code of the express res.status method (https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js) is :

```js
res.status = function status(code) {
  this.statusCode = code;
  return this;
};
```

However, when my `createUserViaEmail()` function fails, I use `res.status().send()` which means that the first `res.status()` returns `this`.

It seems that in Javascript, returning `this` restore the previous send function, so `done()` was never called.

My unit test works when in my exception catcher, I do :

```js
res.statusCode = e.error.status;
res.send(e);
```

Which is not very clean, I'm looking for a cleaner workaround.